# init.d script won't start in reboot, but works from command line

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sinatra, unicorn, init.d

I know this question has been asked a bajillion times, but I just can't figure this out. I've read every page I can on the topic but nothing I've tried works.

Basically, I have a script in /etc/init.d that works fine from the command line but not on startup. I don't know if it's not running at all or it gets some kind of error.

Robinson is a home-grown Sinatra application.

First, here's the script that's in init.d:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          robinson
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
# Short-Description: robinson initscript
# Description:       robinson
### END INIT INFO

# Do NOT "set -e"

DAEMON=/home/terry/projects/robinson/dev/trunk/installation/control.rb
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/robinson
INSTALLATION_PATH="/home/terry/projects/robinson/dev/trunk/installation"


# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
    $DAEMON $INSTALLATION_PATH start
    ;;
  stop)
    $DAEMON $INSTALLATION_PATH stop
    ;;
  restart)
    $DAEMON $INSTALLATION_PATH restart
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac


:
```

So that script's in /etc/init.d. Its permissions are set like this:

```
init.d # ls -lh robinson 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 839 Nov  2 03:45 robinson
```

I ran update-rc.d on the script. In fact, I even tried running it to remove the script, then add it again:

```
init.d # sudo update-rc.d robinson remove
init.d # sudo update-rc.d robinson defaults
```

If I start the service at the command line...

```
init.d # sudo service robinson start
```

... the service works just fine.

The Sinatra app is extremely simple. Right now I'm just trying to get Sinatra working. Here's the entirety of config.ru:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/base"

# Robinson
class Robinson < Sinatra::Base
    get '/*' do
        return 'hello world'
    end
end

# run request routine
run Robinson
```

This is the nginx configuration file for Robinson

```
# unicorn socket
upstream robinson_unicorn_server {
    server unix:/srv/terry/robinson/sockets/unicorn.sock
        fail_timeout=0;
}
```

unicorn.rb looks like this:

```
# set path to app that will be used to configure unicorn
@dir = '/home/terry/projects/robinson/dev/trunk/installation/'

worker_processes 3
working_directory @dir
timeout 30

# configure for Robinson
robinson_data = '/srv/terry/robinson'

# Specify path to socket unicorn listens to,
# we will use this in our nginx.conf later
listen "#{robinson_data}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Set process id path
pid "#{robinson_data}/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Set log file paths
stderr_path "#{robinson_data}/logs/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{robinson_data}/logs/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

It might be worth noting that when I restart the server, no entries are added to unicorn.stderr.log.

Here's some system info:

```
Operating system: Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1
Kernel and CPU: Linux 4.4.0-98-generic on x86_64
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Not sure what other info to give. Let me know if there's anything I should add.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar before, was to do with the fact of the 'user' who is running the script, when you run from the command line, you're running with sudo.

A solution I use which worked is to set a variable and then execute the script as following

```
# set user to a user with permission to run the scripts (root is overkill)
user=root
case "$1" in
    start)
        sudo -u ${user} /home/script.sh ${1} >> /home/scriptlog.log
    ;;
```

and the same for each method

May help for your situation

Comment: I'll experiment with that, but for now I've kludged it to my satisfaction. I wrote a simple script that checks if the server is running. If it's not, the script starts the server. I put that script into root's crontab. That might not be the s'phisticated way to do it, but it works and I can move on to other things.

Thanks for the help!